# How data get serialized thru webserice?

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I have winform client that pass the object to my webservice (Oracle service).When i intercept the httplog that generates the schema like below

```
<InputDateRange>
  <DateFrom>2014-01-01</DateFrom>
  <ScheduledDate>false</ScheduledDate>
  <DateTo>2014-04-03</DateTo>  
  <DateHence>2 weeks hence</DateHence>
</InputDateRange>
```

DateHenceSpecified is the property from service ,i set bool value false  in C# code

OracleService.DateHenceSpecified = false;

I seen this piece of code from my reference class.

```
          /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool DateHenceSpecified {
        get {
            return this.dateHenceFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.dateHenceFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DateHenceSpecified");
        }
    }
```

How the searlizer knows to omit this element based on the bool value.

if i mentioned in "OracleService.DateHenceSpecified = True" then i get value like below. I don't understand ,who pulls the trigger which element has to generate.

```
<InputDateRange>
    <DateFrom>2014-01-10</DateFrom>
    <ScheduledDate>false</ScheduledDate>
    <DateHence>1 week hence</DateHence>
</InputDateRange>
```

I don't understand here, who create the xml is that client or service ? and who decided to create which element in that xml ?

If its a client how client knows which element has to create based on bool value ?

Comment: It's not the property that is being serialized. As you can see, it has attribute XmlIgnore specified on the property, so it won't actually serialize this property. You should find in reference class DateHence property itself (not DateHenceSpecified).

Comment: Thanks Michael moore that make sense to me